# How to confirm and approve a customer account via Database in bulk Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database

How can we change a customer account confirm and approve a customer account via Database in magento 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run to customer account confirmation :

`UPDATE customer_entity SET confirmation = NULL WHERE email='email@domain.com';`

Approve all customers account via Database :

`UPDATE customer_grid_flat SET is_approved = 'approved' WHERE is_approved IS null`

Comment: The first command works. However, `customer_grid_flat` is a generated table, so I would not recommend updating it manually. To update it, simply reindex `customer_grid`.